# Spinner default value selection error android

Tags: android

I am using spinner and custom adapter(No radio buttons). spinner is selecting 1st value and passing an intent which should not happen.

my requirement is when I click on some item in spinner then only the corresponding action should happen.

my code is as follows.

```
CustomAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomAdapter<String>(this,                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                new String[] { "Add/Delete symbols", "forex","metal" });
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.spinner_button);
chooseMarket.setPrompt("Currency settings");
        chooseMarket.setAdapter(adapter);

chooseMarket.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) {

String selectedItem = chooseMarket.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Add/Delete symbols")) {
//Intent passing here
}

@Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

});
```

//My custom adapter

```
private static class CustomAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        // RadioButton rb = view.findViewById(R.id.)
        textView.setText("");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: if you are using custom adapter then try to call onclick method on its view rather than spinner..

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
private static class CustomAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    // RadioButton rb = view.findViewById(R.id.)
    textView.setText(objects[position]);

    view.setOnclickListner(new OnClickListener){

    String selectedItem = textView.getText().toString();
    if (selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Add/Delete symbols")) {
       //Intent passing here
    }
    }

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: How can I pass intent in setOnclickListner. Intent intent = new Intent(????,NewForex.class); getapplicationcontext() is not working because it is an inner class. If I put a context it is asking me change to static, and startActivity will not work for static objects. 
Please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: Instead of spinner I used dialog box.
[link](http://cssinnovations.blogspot.in/2012/07/selection-list-in-alert-dialog-box.html) This link help me alot